# Who will Kalki marry?

Tags: lakshmi, kali-yuga, devi, kalki

As you all know, Kalki is the avatar that Vishnu will take to end the Kali Yuga. In the Kalki Purana,it is stated that his wife will be Padma,an incarnation of Lakshmi.

However,as per the lore of Vaishno Devi,another incarnation of Lakshmi,Rama promised her that during Kaliyuga, he would take an avatar of Kalki and would then marry her.

Hence,my question is, who will Kalki marry?Padma or Vaishno Devi?

Comment: You linked folk lore with story of Purana. So, bit difficult to answer your question.

Comment: As per Puranas Kalki will have 2 wives-Padma and Roma. Roma will be avatar of Vaishnavi

Comment: @Guest22 Could u cite some sources?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per Kalki Purana, Kalki Avatara will have two wives namely: Padmavati and Rama.

From the Purana's [32nd Chapter](http://www.astrojyoti.com/kalkipuranam7.htm):

> Text 17
>
> LORD KALKI ENJOYS PASTIMES WITH HIS CONSORTS 343
>
> PadmavatI took off her ornaments and rolled on the ground, so that her
>   body was soon covered with dust, although her throat appeared bluish
>   because of the musk. Indeed, it appeared as if she had assumed the
>   form of Lord Siva to vanquish Cupid.
>
> Text 18
>
> Understanding the feelings of His poor, **beloved wives**, knowing that
>   they wanted to perform conjugal pastimes with Him, Lord Kalki, the
>   friend of the distressed, approached them so that He could fulfill
>   their desires.
>
> Texts 19-20
>
> As female elephants meet the king of elephants, **the Lord’s consorts**
>   jubilantly greeted Him within that forest and thus fulfilled their
>   cherished desire. **Thereafter, Lord Kalki, along with His consorts**,
>   mounted an effulgent celestial chariot that coursed through the sky.
>   In this way, they enjoyed amorous pastimes in the Vaibhraja forest,
>   Kuvera forest, and a cave at Mount Mandara.
>
> Text 21
>
> **Lord Kalki enjoyed the nectar of Padmavatl’s lotus-like face, and took
>   pleasure in tightly embracing Rama**. Thus, He became smeared with the
>   kunkuma from their breasts as they affectionately bit His body. The
>   Lord became so overwhelmed by love for His consorts that He appeared
>   to have lost all control over His body.
>
> Text 22
>
> **These two equally beautiful and gentle women embraced Lord Hari**, the
>   supreme enjoyer, to their chest, and thus felt transcendental bliss.
>   The hairs of their bodies stood on end due to transcendental ecstasy
>   and this sight made everyone laugh with glee.
>
> Text 23
>
> After enjoying pastimes of love in many forests, the Lord’s consorts
>   became exhausted and so they went to a nearby lake with their beloved
>   Lord Kalki. As female elephants throw water on the king of elephants,
>   so the uniquely charming consorts of the Lord entered the water of the
>   lake and began to splash water their husband’s transcendental body.

...........

So from the above passages, it becomes clear that Padmavati and Rama both are (or will be) consorts of Lord Kalki.

Comment: Very liberal answer and when I am very imaginative. hahahahaha. Ishwar's leela...